# Why is Rails button_to designation ignoring my method speicifcation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, button-to

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  I’m trying to create a button with a GET submit method, so I created

```
<span class="buttonContainer"><%= button_to "Save", user_my_object_time_matches_create_path(:id => @my_object_time.id), :method => "GET", :class => 'btn saveDetails', :remote => true %></span>
```

but what is actually getting created is a form with a POST action.

```
<form class="button_to" method="post" action="/user_my_object_time_matches/create?id=d64bbe61-21cc-477a-aa11-ab4ff5cac66c" data-remote="true"><input class="btn saveDetails" type="submit" value="Save"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="ENx/qK8hoRdR1DVa/99rQGQeJiaoQNPXx6k/xTwDy6KkPAUC1KyHM8qiC1SiCbeNsgghhMh7sjsu8c+2e7cnfg=="></form>
```

What am I doing wrong in the above?  How do I get the above to become a GET submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The allowed values for `:method` are the *symbols* `:get`, `:post`, `:put`, `:patch` and `:delete`. Use `method: :get`, not `method: 'GET'`.

The string `'get'` will work, as a quirk of `button_to`'s implementation, but that shouldn't be depended upon. The string `'GET'` absolutely will not work, and will instead use the default value for `:method`, which is `:post`.